# Understanding the statement $S = \{x : x \in S\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In *Introduction to analysis* by Rosenlicht there is the following set definition:

$$S = \{x : x \in S\}$$

There is no specific context to this it's just that I find this a little recursive. I would read it "$S$ is a set of $x$ for which every $x$ is an element of $S$". Is that correct?

Comment: Does the book actually give that as the _definition_ of $S$? I hope not - that would make no sense. More likely is the author just presents it as a true fact, _not_ a definition.

Comment: You're reading it wrong, by the way. It says "$S$ is **the** set of $x$ such that $x\in S$". "the" versus "a" is hugely important here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right! This definition is recursive and meaningless. You are also reading it correctly as something like "the set of everything that is an element of S"

The problem here is that there is no definition of set. It is a primary concept. The reason why we don't define "set" is because you would have defined it in terms of other things, which themselves are defined in terms of "lower-level things" and the chain would never end.

So, unless you really want to go deeper into the foundations of mathematics and set theory, for most practical purposes, you can just think of a set as an "arbitrary collection of elements" that is defined ONLY by its elements, and where order does not matter.

For example, if $S:=\{1,2,3\}, T:=\{2,3,1\}$ and $U:=\{x \in \mathbb{Z} : 0<x<4\}$, then $S, T$ and $U$ are the same set.

Comment: So what I have specified is the most general way we can define a set with mathematical notation? If we put any other condition after the colon it would already be something specific.

Comment: I wouldn't say so, because that's not a definition at all. It's like saying that "a continuous function is any function that is continuous". Note that not only you are defining $S$ in terms of $S$ itself, but also the notation sign "$\in$" only makes sense once the concept of set is already defined

Comment: Hmm, what is the point of that line in the book then? What does the author want to say with that?

Comment: I don't have the book within my hands, so who knows

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Analysis-Maxwell-Rosenlicht/dp/1388262800   You can look inside the book, it is on the 3rd page

Comment: @MichaelMunta It's not a definition, it just says that "for any set, we have....", meaning that statement is true for any set (see Mauro Allegranza's final paragraph)

Comment: So it can be thought of like every set $S$ has certain elements $x$ for which there is an implied condition of $x \in S$? It is just something that is universally true for a set that contains some elements.

Comment: @MichaelMunta Sure, if $x$ is an element of $S$, then $x \in S$ This holds for any conceivable $x$ and $S$

Comment: It's a definition. It's just not a predicative definition.

Answer (score 3):

The so-called [Set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) is used to "specify" a set.

Its syntax is

> $S = \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$

where formula $\varphi(x)$ expresses a property (a condition).

The meaning is :

> "the set $S$ is made of all and only those object that satisfy condition $\varphi(x)$".

As a way to define a new set $S$, it makes little sense to use $x ∈ S$ as "specifying condition".

But obviously, if we are **not** defining $S$ but we already know it, then we have trivially that $S = \{ x \mid x∈S \}$.